# Why I can't navigate after set a fix IP on a Linux machine virtualized on VMWare?

Tags: linux, networking, ip, vmware, ifconfig

I am not so into networking and I am finding the following problem trying to configure a fix IP on a Linux virtual machine virtualized on VmWare.

The networking mode condigured on VmWare is **NAT** and using **DHCP** instead fix IP it is working fine.

I have perform the following steps:

1) On the Windows host machine I retrieved the information related to my gateway (the router) performing **ipconfig** statment, obtaining:

[image]

So **192.168.1.1** is my router IP address of my domestic lan

2) Into my virtualized VM I set the network configuration in this way:

[image]

So as you can see in the previous screenshot the IP is set as **192.168.1.100** that should be reacheable by the defined subnet mask.

The problem is that restarting this machine I can't navigate on Internet and I can't ping anything from the console. It is not working.

This is the output of **infconfig** statment:

[image]

What is wrong? What am I missing? Have I to configure something related to static IP also on my router or there is something wrong in my previous configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your Virtual Machine's network interface is on VMNet8 (NAT) adapter, you must set an IP address in 192.168.241.0 subnet according to ipconfig you show. And the default gateway should be set to 192.168.241.2. 
VMware NAT will forward the traffic.

If you want to configure an IP address directly in 192.168.1.0 subnet (your wireless device), you need to use a bridge, but I don't think VMplayer offers this option.